Cloud functions deployment failed
I'm trying to use cloud functions to create docs in firestore it says:

✔  Deploy complete!

But in the console I see an error icon beside the function and it says deployment failed.
I get this too, but I believe it's a warning:

⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually

here's my code
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
// const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

initializeApp();

// Create a Firestore instance
const firestore = getFirestore();

// Create a Cloud Function to handle POST requests
exports.addContact = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (
    req.query.userId &&
      req.query.firstName &&
      req.query.lastName &&
      req.query.phoneNumber
  ) {
    try {
      const contactRef = await firestore
          .collection(`users/${req.query.userId}/contacts`)
          .add({
            firstName: req.query.firstName,
            lastName: req.query.lastName,
            phoneNumber: req.query.phoneNumber,
            approved: false,
          });

      res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Contact added successfully.",
        contactId: contactRef.id,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({success: false, error: error.message});
    }
  }
});



It sounds like you're talking about two different unrelated problems here.  The first happens during deployment using the Firebase CLI, and the second happens when using the console when not using Firebase at all.  Please focus on a single problem along unless you can show that they are related (I don't see that they are).

yeah you're right I modified the post

The deploy error has nothing to do with your code.  Please see the duplicate question.
